# Domain Driven Design - Identity domain and Core domain persistence issue

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I am starting to learn about DDD, and I started to developing a simple app which handles university theses. The idea is as follows:

A student writes a thesis which then needs to defend in order to complete a course(bachelor, masters etc). 3 professors needs to revise a thesis giving grades and comments, after which there's an examination, where a student needs to defend his/her thesis. Each course have separate thesis, and students can take up more than one course in uni.
Students will have their accounts to add written thesis, professors to review the thesis and give grades, and clerk's from dean office will set up thesis defense etc.

Now I will have several entities, for example Professor, Student, Clerk. I will also have identity context with users.

**The question is: how do I connect the dots, between users from identity domain with my entites from core domain modelling the persistence layer ?**

Professor will have ProfessorID VO, Student will have StudentID VO and Clerk ClerkID VO as ID. Now user will have UserID, but a user can be student or professor or clerk.

**Do I need to put userID on my entities (Student,Professor,Clerk) so that I have some connection to user accounts ? It seems like pushing application concerns into domain, where there's no concept of Users at all.**

**Other idea, would be to have the same ID for user and specific Entity class. For example when student creates its account, app generates an ID, creates a student with this ID and user with the same ID. This also seems quite weird.**

Many thanks for help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the concepts that DDD warns us about is Canonical Model; this basically means having an officially accepted as authentic and authoritative common language that is shared between the users on the domain model (domain experts) and the developers (tech experts). The problem with that is that this model can grow to a size that hardly anyone understands.

With that in mind, regardless of where the User ID specifically lives, each more specific model such as Student, Professor and whatnot, should probably handle the specific business rules, business definitions and biz logic underneath it as opposed the more generic User. That way, it'll allow people have a better sense of Multiple Canonical Models existing in your system that can be more easily understood by people and the ecosystem you're building.

As for the connecting with the persistence layer, I see that as something less central of the DDD realm, since you can apply whichever architectural pattern makes sense to you whether that's MVC or design patterns such as Active Record, Repository Pattern, etc.

One cool exercise worth experimenting with is Context Mapping, where it'll allow you to think about "things" as nouns and verbs/events.

Comment: Yes, domain classes will handle the business logic, but authentication and authorization connected with specific users, will live in the application layer. But the question is: will it be bad design if I store userID on my domain classes ? Or should I stick with having the same ID as for domain classes on users (which of course are not part of the domain but I need to persist all of this somehow)

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to say that the concept of user is likely only useful in contexts like logging in and perhaps for profile management: that profile could include associating a user with a domain role (i.e. this user has this professor ID).